# C ABI float structs as parameter

Tags: c, abi

I'm working on some zig bindings but as the language [doesn't have complete C ABI support](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/1481) I'm trying to hack it to at least work somewhat. From the issue above I know that normal struct & union parameters <= 16 bytes are broken down into pieces without any modification with the exception of structs or unions that are just floats and <= 16. My question is: what does C to those structs?

Edit (additional information):
When passing a struct as a parameter in C, C handles different kinds of structs differently. For structs that are 16 bytes are smaller there are two kinds: "normal" and structs that are only made up of floats. I know how C passes normal structs, by just breaking it down into its pieces and pushing them onto the stack, but I don't know how it passes only-float structs.

Platform information:
64-bit macOS, compiler is apple clang version 11.0.3

Comment: Would you like to clarify your question? (I can hardly understand what your problem is)

Comment: When passing a struct as a parameter in C, C handles different kinds of structs differently. For structs that are 16 bytes are smaller there are two kinds: "normal" and structs that are only made up of floats. I know how C passes normal structs, by just breaking it down into its pieces and pushing them onto the stack, but I don't know how it passes only-float structs.

Comment: that is implementation-specified. Also you may want to add that to your question **body** as people usually vote to close questions without reading the comments

Comment: Since this is implementation specified, you may want to include what platform, compiler, compiler version, etc. (Or one get no idea because it is, "implementation specified")

Comment: You can of course compile a test C program and look at the assembly to see what happens.  For instance, [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M7rto3) demonstrates that on x86-64 with SYSV ABI, a struct of four floats is passed in two xmm registers.

Comment: I'm on 64-bit macOS, compiler is apple clang version 11.0.3